# ¿Cómo opera la variable 'shorts', en este script

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

La función que muestro a continuación,

```
# # Calculation of position
def calculate_moving_averages(data, window_fast, window_slow):   
    data[window_fast_label] = data[nom_val].ewm(window_fast).mean()
    data[window_slow_label] = data[nom_val].rolling(window_slow).mean()
    data['position'] = np.where( data[window_fast_label] > data[window_slow_label], 1, -1)
    return data 


data = df_value.copy(deep=True)
data = calculate_moving_averages(data, window_fast, window_slow)
```

Me devuelve

```
data ["position"].value_counts()

-1    1265
 1     990
Name: position, dtype: int64
```

Al utilizar la variable 'shorts=False', de la siguiente manera,

```
# # Calculation of position
# Sin la variable 'shorts', obtendríamos 1 y -1, en vez de 1 y 0.
def calculate_moving_averages(data, window_fast, window_slow, shorts=False):   
    data[window_fast_label] = data[nom_val].ewm(window_fast).mean()
    data[window_slow_label] = data[nom_val].rolling(window_slow).mean()
    if shorts:
        data['position'] = np.where(
            data[window_fast_label] > data[window_slow_label], 1, -1)
    else:
        data['position'] = np.where(
            data[window_fast_label] > data[window_slow_label], 1, 0)
    return data 


data = df_value.copy(deep=True)
data = calculate_moving_averages(data, window_fast, window_slow, shorts=False)
```

me devuelve,

```
data ["position"].value_counts()

0    1265
1     990
Name: position, dtype: int64
```

No acabo de entender cómo opera ya que entiendo que, la variable **'shorts = False'**, nunca cambia a **'TRUE'**, por lo que la segunda parte del bucle, a partir de la sentencia **'else'**, nunca se va a ejecutar.
Agradeceré me expliquéis qué no estoy entendiendo bien.

Comment: Si `short` es `False` entonces entra en el `else`  y según eso te retorna el resultado. No hay ni guía magia negra ni nada del otro mundo

Comment: Si 'shorts =False' y 'data[window_fast_label] > data[window_slow_label]', introduce un 1.

Comment: Creo que ya  lo entiendo. Si 'shorts =False' y 'data[window_fast_label] > data[window_slow_label]', introduce un 1. Si  esa condición no se cumple, se ejecuta 'else',y como la condición es la misma que en el paso anterior, donde se cumplía , introduce el 0.

Comment: Perdón. Debería decir '....donde no se cumplía...'